# Java Streams checking for nulls

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to convert this piece code into streams

```
List<ECSUSU> listOfUSUs = msccRequest.getUsedServiceUnit();
if (listOfUSUs != null) {
     ECSUSU usedServiceUnit = listOfUSUs.get(0);
     if (usedServiceUnit.getCcTime() != null && usedServiceUnit.getCcTime() > 0) {
          return UnitType.SECONDS;
      } else {
          return UnitType.BYTES;
      }
}
```

I would thought this will work but I am getting NullPointerException. 
msccRequest.getUsedServiceUnit() might return null , that's why I need the check

```
 msccRequest.getUsedServiceUnit().stream()
                    .filter(list -> list != null)
                    .limit(1)
                    .map(usedServiceUnit -> {
                        if (usedServiceUnit.getCcTime() != null && usedServiceUnit.getCcTime() > 0) {
                            return UnitType.SECONDS;
                        } else {
                            return UnitType.BYTES;
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `msccRequest.getUsedServiceUnit()` returns `null`, the attempt to call the `stream()` method on that will throw a `NullPointerException`. I expect the NPE comes from that. You need to check for null before calling the `stream()` method.

Also note that your two pieces of code are not equivalent (even if the above problem is fixed). The first code only checks the first element of the list, while the second takes the first non-null element.

Also, you are only interested in a single element of the list. Then `findFirst` seems to be a better choice than `limit`.

```
List<ECSUSU> listOfUSUs = msccRequest.getUsedServiceUnit();
if (listOfUSUs != null) {
    return listOfUSUs.stream()
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .findFirst()
        .map(usedServiceUnit -> {
                if (usedServiceUnit.getCcTime() != null && usedServiceUnit.getCcTime() > 0) {
                    return UnitType.SECONDS;
                } else {
                    return UnitType.BYTES;
                }
            })
        .orElse(/* default value */);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i've not got a chance to try this out , i will reply asap.

Answer (score 2):

`filter` applies to individual elements of the `Stream` (A `Stream` iterates over each element in the list), so if `msccRequest.getUsedServiceUnit()` returns `null`, the `.stream()` invocation will throw an NPE. If you need to ensure that the list itself is not `null`, I suggest that you wrap it in an `Optional`, like this:

```
Optional<List<ECSUSU>> list = Optional.ofNullable(msccRequest.getUsedServiceUnit())
```

Then use `ifPresent` to implement the iteration:

```
list.ifPresent(notNullListForSure -> notNullListForSure.stream())
```

etc

Comment: yeah but why not a standard if statement and perform the stream operation only if the list is not null?? 
`List<ECSUSU> listOfUSUs = msccRequest.getUsedServiceUnit();
if(listOfUSUs != null) //do stream stuff`

Comment: That's an option (pun intended) if you prefer the non-functional approach. Since the OP wanted to convert to `Stream`, I simply extended it in the same fashion.

Comment: Thanks, i've not got a chance to try this out , i will reply asap.